# How to replace text in split sub-string in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**sample value in DB:** one-two-three.js

**Need to format like this:** one two three

I split the field using `$split` aggregate, but after this how to replace "-" with " " ?

**replaceAll("-", " ")**

```
$push: {
  name: {$arrayElemAt:[{$split: ["$name" , "."]}, 0]},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- your tried code, `$set`, `$split` name with `.` and get first element using `$arrayElemAt`
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `name` array after converting form string using `$split`
- `$concat` to concat string with space and return value, this will return with extra space in first position of string, and `$substr` will remove that first position space

```
  {
    $set: {
      name: {
        $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$file", "."] }, 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      name: {
        $substr: [
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: { $split: ["$name", "-"] },
              initialValue: "",
              in: { $concat: ["$$value", " ", "$$this"] }
            }
          },
          1,
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CQG8Rg0s8KF)

Comment: But, it doesn't split the ".js"

Comment: that you have already did in your question, i have merged both in answer, you can check..